# How to count in 1 sql query the number of rows from an other table

Tags: php, sql, database

i have a problem. I have a table on my website with 3 columns like this:

[image]

This data is out of 2 database tables, the title and yes/no columns are from the table quizzes and the Number of questions is out of the questions table.
I want that users can sort per column, so that you can sort the title asc and desc. I already have this with title and yes/no but not with questions because i dont know how to do that in 1 sql query.

The outcome of that sql query should be the Title, the number of questions that quiz has and if it is yes or no.

If this is to vague please tell me so i will try to write a better explanation. if you need an example of the database please tell me too.

Comment: does your table have some column like "userid"?

Comment: and does the question table?

Comment: can u show us your query?

Comment: @IvoP my table questions has a column named quiz, this stores the id of the quiz this questions is a child of

Comment: @YeLwinSoe I have 5 query's, every query sorts on an different column. This is one of them: SELECT title, private, id  FROM quizzes WHERE user = '$user_id' ORDER BY title asc LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage

Comment: @NiekBrouwer u'll need to JOIN two table and u can sort any field u want to sort among two tables instead of multiple query.
Example - 

SELECT title, private, quizzes.id, questions.yes_or_no_field FROM quizzes JOIN questions ON questions.quizzes_id=quizzes.id WHERE user = '$user_id' ORDER BY yes_or_no_field asc LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage

I hope it's help.

Comment: Would sorting the resultset afterwards be an option? [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079025/sorting-the-results-of-a-mysql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query could be something like :

```
SELECT quizes.title, quizes.id, count(q.id) AS aantal
FROM quizes 
LEFT JOIN questions AS q ON q.quizid= quizes.id
GROUP BY quizes.title, quizes.id
ORDER BY aantal DESC
```

**edit**

changed names of table and columns as comments reveilled them

Comment: it worked, thank you. i'm now gonna learn what this query exactly does because else it will only solve the problem and my knowledge wont go up